# Swift UILabel line spacing of break lines

Tags: swift, uilabel, spacing, paragraph, line-spacing

I have a text that comes from multiple sources and ends with \n\n for a line break in UILabel that has lines set to 0 through Storyboard.

For example:

```
let text = “Some text at the beginning of the paragraph that is this long\n\nSecond type of text\n\nSome longer text that is on later on in the paragraph”
```

The output is correct:

> Some text at the beginning of the paragraph that is this long
>
> Second type of text
>
> Some longer text that is on later on in the paragraph

I have changed the line spacing to slightly increase the gaps between lines but can’t change the height of the empty line. I want the line break to be approximately half the size of a normal line break. I tried after/before paragraph settings but can’t get an empty line to be half the size.

Any idea if this is possible and what is the best way to achieve this through storyboard or programmatically.

----- Edit:

This is what I tried:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

            paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 0.1
            paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore = 0.1
            
            let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
            attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
            
            cell.firstLabel?.attributedText = attrString
```

Comment: By modifying the `paragraphSpacing` of the paragraph, the gaps between the line increases.

Comment: Tried it, it had no effect.

Comment: I got it work in Playground. What's your full code when setting the content? Are you sure you correctly set `label.attributedText`, and not `label.text`?

Comment: Look at my edit, this is what I tried, the gap does reduce slightly but it is still massive. I want the empty row to be around twice the size of normal line spacing.

Comment: I thought you wanted to increase the space. Why not removing the "\n\n"? .replacingOccurrences(of: "\n\n", with: "\n")

Comment: Because then the spacing will be the same for each line. I need a line break after every sentence, but want the line break to be small. Small enough so it looks more like standard text line spacing, but not as big as an actual empty line. Deleting the \n will give me the same line spacing for all text without a space I am looking for.

Comment: I have found a fix, setting paragraphSpacing to -5 works, but is that an approved way of doing it? As in will the negative spacing not have issues?